# Resource ID NotFound when Setting TextView's texts From AsyncTask

Tags: android

i am Trying to Set Texts of some TextView from an AsyncTask like this:

```
class InfoLoader extends AsyncTask<Params, String, Result>{


final String groupName;
final TextView populationTV;
final TextView passwordstateTV;
final TextView publicstateTV;
RoomInfo info;

    protected InfoLoader(final String groupName,final TextView populationTV, final 
 TextView passwordstateTV, final TextView publicstateTV) {
    super();
    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.populationTV = populationTV;
    this.passwordstateTV = passwordstateTV;
    this.publicstateTV = publicstateTV;
 }

                    @Override
                    protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {


                        try {
                             info = 
 MultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(MyService.connection,groupName+"@conference.reza-hp");
                        } catch (NoResponseException | XMPPErrorException
                                | NotConnectedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                         new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    if(populationTV==null){
                                        System.out.println("Its null");
                                    }
                                    if(info==null){
                                        System.out.println("Info null");
                                    }
                                     populationTV.setText(info.getOccupantsCount());

                                      if(info.isPasswordProtected()==true){
                                          passwordstateTV.setText("Yes");
                                      }else if(info.isPasswordProtected()==false){
                                          passwordstateTV.setText("No");
                                      }

                                      if(info.isMembersOnly()==true){
                                          publicstateTV.setText("Members Only");
                                      }else if(info.isMembersOnly()==false){
                                          publicstateTV.setText("Public");
                                      }

                                }
                            });


                        return null;

 }


 }
```

the TextViews are from My ListView, and im Sure they are Not null, but i retrieve this error:

```
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): Process: com.lifemate.lmmessenger, PID:   
 3063
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063): 
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):    at 
 android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):    at 
 android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):    at  
 com.lifemate.lmmessenger.listviewengine.SelfMUCPinnedHeaderAdapter$InfoLoader$1.
 run(SelfMUC
 PinnedHeaderAdapter.java:328)
 07-12 20:40:57.909: E/AndroidRuntime(3063):    at  
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
```

but im quite sure that i Have Done some Thing Like This Before, Do you See Any Thing Wrong here Guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an integer argument, which corresponds to the version of setText that takes a resource identifier. You should be using something like:

```
populationTV.setText(Integer.toString(info.getOccupantsCount()));
```

Comment: That Worked, Thanks alot dear, all the time i thought Some Thing is wrong with TextView ID's